# How to load DataService before MainViewModel when using MVVMLight ViewModelLocator in WPF app?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm-light

My goal was to load one of my data services before the rest of the application (visible UI).

My MVVMlight setup was pretty well stock, before trying to pre-load my data service.

- The ViewModelLocator is initialized in the App.Xaml.
- The ViewModels and DataServices are registered, and work fine.

In my App.xaml.cs the main view is loaded like so.

```
var mainWindow = new View.MainWindow();
mainWindow.Show();
```

To pre-load my data service I set my data service to createInstanceImmediately, then added the following just above the mainWindow code.

```
DataService dataService = SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance<IDataService>();
```

That line generates an exception "CommonServiceLocator.ActivationException: 'Type not found in cache: Namespace.IDataService.'"

If move that line down below the mainWindow code, it works just fine.

My first thought was that it was a timing issue, but if I add a delay, I still get the error.  So it appears that the application resource is not loading until after a view is loaded.  I wouldn't not have thought that to be, since the app.xaml and the app.xaml.cs are really part of the same class.  Regardless, I'm not sure how to get around this, or if I even can.

Why doesn't the ViewModelLocator load without a view?  Is there a way to force it to load the application resource manually?  Or is there a better way?

Comment: You need to move service registration before creating the window. It should be one of the first lines in your App class contructor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did finally find a solution.

The trick is to manually instantiate the `ViewModelLocator` from the application resources.

```
private ViewModelLocator viewModelLocator = App.Current.Resources["Locator"] as ViewModelLocator
```

The view models can then be accessed via `viewModelLocator.Main` (or whatever property name you assign) if needed.

Placement of this bit is important.  It will not work from the App Constructor, but it does from the Application_Startup Event handler.  I ended up putting in its own class that I load from Application_Startup, more to keep my App.xaml.cs clean than otherwise.

After using this for a little while, I am growing fond of it and may start using more often.  It makes hooking up my events between view models quite easy, when my needs don't require the messenger service.